# Command error when downloading 'main' module

Tags: python

When encountering this problem, I had tried to download the 'main' module from both the command prompt and the PowerShell. However, the same error result was shown. How can I solve this problem? This is the error message:

```
Collecting main
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/f4/445fbd86d9ebd133a03a263482f72dd539ccc90a0c29693222903e5e145e/main-0.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: main
    Running setup.py install for main ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Python 3.8.1\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\asuit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9tqrshss\\main\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\asuit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9tqrshss\\main\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\asuit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oc5gc9jc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=
         cwd: C:\Users\asuit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9tqrshss\main\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_scripts
    creating build
    creating build\scripts-3.8
    error: file 'C:\Users\asuit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9tqrshss\main\main' does not exist
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Python 3.8.1\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\asuit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9tqrshss\\main\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\asuit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9tqrshss\\main\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\asuit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oc5gc9jc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.
```

The pip commands that I used are python -m pip install --user main for Command Prompt and pip install main for Windows PowerShell

Comment: welcome to stack overflow `file 'C:\Users\asuit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9tqrshss\main\main' does not exist` says not exists

Comment: Please post the full `pip install` command line you used.

Comment: When I check the project's venv files, the main module was there, but when I click to install the module in the IDE, it said to download via the command